# How to provide a document preview as a thumbnail independent of file type

Tags: html, css, gmail, thumbnails, attachment

In gmail when a file is sent as an attachment to an email, the recipient(s) can see a small portion of the contents of the file before even hovering over it. Now I'm very curius and in fact interested in implementing this in my own application. I've tried inspect element but couldn't quite get how they do this. Ok, with images I can somewhat understand how it's done. But how about pdf, word or excel document? Do they take a snapshot of some portion of the file and store it along with the attachment to later show it inside a container? Has anyone been able to do this? Is just html and css enough?

Answer (score 4):

May be you have found a solution....

But am just updating an answer i just found
If you use `Krajee Plugin` then you can get that type of preview of the file. Its just not giving `gmail` like file preview but also giving other type plugin to upload and preview the images and files(almost every type). Giving below the links for your reference.

[File Preview Demo](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-management-demo)

[File Preview Icon Demo](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-icons-demo)